How are isometries and Möbius maps related?
I'm trying to answer the three questions after this introductory definition:
An isometry is a mapping $f : C → C$ such that $|f(z) − f(w)|  = |z − w|$  for every $z, w ∈ C$ (which means that distances do not change).
(a) Give an example of an entire function that is not an isometry.
(b) Are all isometries Möbius maps?
(c) Are all Möbius maps isometries? (You can ignore the point at infinity.)
Concerning (a), an example is maybe any constant function, which is like a black hole, that shrinks the entire complex plane into a point.
Furthermore I think that the correct answer to (b) is no. Rotations and translations preserve distances, if I'm not mistaken, and they are Möbius maps, but what about reflections? Is complex conjugation a reflection? Does that means that it preserves distances? If so, then it's an isometry, but it can't be a Möbius map as it's not holomorphic while Möbius maps are. Am I right?
The last question, (c), seems quite easy. There are Möbius maps which map circles to lines, and we can choose two points far away from each other on a line which is the image of a circle, but the possible distance between the preimages is limited. So the answer should be no again, I think. Do you agree?

Yes, that's all correct. For b), complex conjugation is indeed a reflection, hence an isometry, but not holomorphic, so not a Mobius transformation. A simpler example for c) is just any scaling, e.g. $z \mapsto 2z$.

Good to hear that I'm right, although my example for (c) was poorly chosen

Towards part (c):
For arbitrary Mobius maps as $f(z) = \Large\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ with $ad-bc\neq 0$, we have forall $w,z\in\mathbb{C}$:
$$|f(z)-f(w)| := \bigg|\frac{az+b}{cz+d}-\frac{aw+b}{cw+d}\bigg|$$
$$= \dots = \bigg|\frac{(ad-bc)}{(cz+d)(cw+d)}\bigg|\cdot|z-w| $$
$$=: C(a,b,c,d,z,w)\cdot|z-w|,$$
where Commutativity of complex numbers and Multiplicativity of the norm are assumed.
From here, one can see the failure of the Isometry condition with choices of $a,b,c,d$ making $C(z,w)\not\equiv 1$.
Using Qiaochu Yuan's suggestion, $f(z) := 2z$, a.k.a. $(a,b,c,d)= (2,0,0,1),$ yields $C \equiv 2$.
Inversion, $f(z) := \frac{1}{z}$, a.k.a. $(a,b,c,d)= (0,1,1,0)$, yields $C(z,w) = \bigg|\frac{1}{zw}\bigg|$. Etc.

I think your answer for (a) is sufficient, however for (b), rational functions from $\mathbb{C}$ to itself are meromorphic. When we consider these Mobius maps of the Riemann sphere, it's a different story, where the notion of holomorphic becomes complicated with charts $``\psi\circ f\circ \varphi^{-1}"$. Perhaps overkill, but I think the same proof works. Conjugation isn't holomorphic, so its composition with charts shouldn't be and hence as a mapping of Riemann spheres it won't be holomorphic and hence it can't be a Mobius map as all of them are holos of the Riemann sphere.

Good point! Perhaps I should have written that Möbius maps are meromorphic (not holomorphic) while the complex conjugation map (which is isometric) isn't complex differentiable anywhere?

Yes, I think treating everything in $\mathbb{C}$ would be the way to go
